# How to authorize an API Request with PHP CURL

Tags: php, http-headers

**UPDATE: SOLVED IT!**

I need to authorize an API request to a stock market website using cURL with PHP for a school project.

The example I get for authorization from the website is:

> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 12345678900987654321-abc34135acde13f13530" https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/accounts

So, would I have to set it up like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headr = array();
$headr[ ] = 'Authorization: Bearer myAPIKEYGOESHERE';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);

//Then I'd Place the Rest of parameters
```

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't know if it is correct. Is it?

Comment: When you post something on SO you are supposed to try it first, only *then* ask for help if you have a problem. Look at [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to know how to ask homework questions and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for questions in general.

Comment: I'm testing it right now. Sorry for bothering you though. I'm new and didn't read the rules yet.